# Fedora 16 Yakuake keybinding failure ( retracts but will not dropdown )

Tags: fedora

On fedora 16 I've installed yakuake, and when I hit F12 ( default keybind ) the terminal retracts, but on hitting F12 again it won't deploy down. Does anyone have a thought as to why F12 isn't being processed properly?

One weird effect that I've seen is that when I hit F12 with a konsole open a tilde is generated on the command line. I've looked at the keybindings for kde & for konsole and nothing is bound to F12.

Comment: I'm going to rebuild from source and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: KDE4 on Fedora16 -- cmake 2.8.7 is buggy and yakuake cannot be built at the moment.

Comment: I fixed it using GNOME shortcut insted of "yakuake" one.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem now, and I had a bunch of shells still running that I didn't want to lose.  Here's what I did; you can probably find a cleaner way:

- Run /usr/bin/qdbusviewer (ships with qt-x11)
- Scroll down to org.kde.yakuake on the left hand side of the "Session Bus" tab, click it
- On the right side, navigate to:

  - yakuake/

    - MainWindow_1/

      - com.trolltech.Qt.QWidget

        - Scroll down to "Method: show" and double-click it.

Yay!  Doing this made yakuake regain its sanity (i.e. F12 works once again).

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above answer on Ubuntu 12.04, but it didn't work.

In the end, I disabled the open/retract keyboard shortcut from within yakuake, then I set a global keyboard shortcut from Unity->Keyboard, that just executes "yakuake". Fortunately, the authors of yakuake put a listener in place so only a single instance of it can run at a time. When it detects another instance attempting to open, it just triggers the retract/drop-down function. Bravo!

Answer (score 3):

for everyone who still experience same problem this is the fix.

in System->keyboard->shortcuts->custom shortcuts make new .

Name: yakuake
Command: qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window toggleWindowState

save -> then bind your shortcut and you are done. Tested and working in fedora 22

Comment: I ended up with the same solution in my Ubuntu 16.04. After upgrade from 14.04 my yakuake stopped functioning properly, more precisely refused to open after successfully retracting by pressing a previously bound from yakuake configuration menu key. Building from source or deleting kde related to yakuake user's configuration files didn't help as well.

Comment: When using this method, the yakuake window is not gaining focus, after being shown. The focus stays on the window that had it before pressing the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by disabling the shortcut in Yakuake itself ("none"), then going to KDE Control Panel, Global Keyboard Shortcuts, find Yakuake from the dropdown list of apps, and set open/retract as desired.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me running Manjaro Linux with KDE. `plasmashell -v` reports 5.17.5

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using GNOME shortcut (as `/usr/bin/yakuake`), instead of `yakuake` shortcut.